# EXPO save photo in Pictures after taking it from Camera

Tags: android, react-native, camera, expo

EXPO React Native, running the app on Expo Go on my android mobile.

I am trying to save photo taken by the Camera to Pictures folder on my Android device.
It just not happening. Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

```
takePicture = async () => {
  const { uri } = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
  console.log(‘uri’, uri);
  const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri);
  console.log(‘asset’, asset.filename);
  MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync(‘Pictures’, asset)
  .then(() => {
    Alert.alert(‘Album created!’)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    Alert.alert(‘An Error Occurred!’)
  });
   this.setState({ photoId: this.state.photoId + 1 });
   Vibration.vibrate(); 
}
```

my console return the uri after photo taken but asset.file is not returned it is like nothing is happening there. any help is appreciated.

I dumped medialibrary for imagepicker and it worked with this code

```
  _takePhoto = async () => {
    const {
      status: cameraPerm
    } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);

    const {
      status: cameraRollPerm
    } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);

    // only if user allows permission to camera AND camera roll
    if (cameraPerm === 'granted' && cameraRollPerm === 'granted') {
      let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
        allowsEditing: false,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 0.2,
      });

      this._handleImagePicked(pickerResult);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Did the Camera app not already save the image to file? As why whould you otherwise get an uri? What would that uri stand for then?

Comment: I got the cash path in the consolelog like this one "uri file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540eyatme%252Fcameraapp6/Camera/70b24b78-d44e-43e2-b4fe-d0d17e903e1a.jpg"

Comment: Well that looks a path to a file already. Why would you save another file? I asked that before but you did not react. You did not answer my questions to begin with. Are you serious?

Comment: I got the uri and that in temp cash. I need to move it to an accessible folder like Pictures. I am using MediaLibrary to do just that, but when I try to get file assets "const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(uri);" asset return nothing and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function of expo-media-library but you can't specify the folder.

```
await MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(uri);
```

I'm thinking of using this function below to move the image to a specific folder.

```
MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync(assets, album, copyAssets)
```

You can check this url [Expo Media Library](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/media-library/)

Comment: I changed it to this:
takePicture = async () => {
    if(this.camera){
              let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync().then(data => { 
                const assets = MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(data.uri); 
                console.log('assets', assets.id)
                console.log('datauri',data.uri)
              console.log('photo', photo);
              })
    }
            this.setState({ photoId: this.state.photoId + 1 });
            Vibration.vibrate();
  }
Result Photo and assets are undefined